# Change on scope not reflecting on modal UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a button that is disabled and has to enabled after some time.

I'm trying to do it using `$timeout` and `ng-disabled`, but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<button id="resend_button" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-click="reenviar_confirmacao()" ng-disabled="!buttonEnabled">{{'RESEND-CONFIRMATION' | translate}}</button>
```

Modal opening:

```
ngDialog.open({
    id: 'confirmation',
    template: '../../../templates/confirmacao-sms.html',
    preCloseCallback: callback,
    backdrop  : 'static',
    keyboard  : false,
    scope: $scope
});
```

Function:

```
$timeout(function(){
    console.log(angular.element("#resend_button"));
    // Tried this but didn't work aswell
    angular.element("#resend_button").removeAttr('disabled');

    $scope.buttonEnabled = true;
    $scope.$apply();
}, 2000)
```

It changes the `$scope.buttonEnblaed` value, but it only refresh the button status if I close and re-open the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Write the timeout inside `$scope.$apply`

```
$scope.$apply(function(){

    $timeout(function(){
        console.log(angular.element("#resend_button"));
        // Tried this but didn't work aswell
        angular.element("#resend_button").removeAttr('disabled');

        $scope.buttonEnabled = true;

    }, 2000)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a redundant `ng-controller`. Deleting one of them did the trick.